# How to make MediaLibraryPicker Field required in Orchard custom module

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I have added MediaLibraryPicker field in my custom module and I want to make this field required. Please help me.
`ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("UserProfilePart", part => part
                .WithField("Photo", field => field
                    .OfType("MediaLibraryPickerField")
                    .WithDisplayName("User Photo")));`

When submit the form. User need to select at least one image from media library.

Comment: When submit my custom module form in admin I want to add validation for MediaLibraryPicker field. When save form user have to select at least one image from media library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added setting of MediaLibraryPicker Filed like and working fine.

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("UserProfilePart", part => part
     .WithField("Photo", field => field .OfType("MediaLibraryPickerField"
     .WithDisplayName("User Photo").WithSetting("MediaLibraryPickerFieldSettings.Required", "true")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Add .WithSetting("Required", "true")